# Filter Array of dictionary. Dictionary has another array as its key value pair. Filter array based on key which is present in that array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

My array structure is like this

```
    Array1
    [
    Dict 1:
    Key1 = Value1
    Key2 = Array2 
                [Key3 = Value1]

    Dict 2:
    Key1 = Value1
    Key2 = Array2 
                [Key3 = Value2”]

    Dict 3:
    Key1 = Value1
    Key2 = Array2 
                [Key3 = Value2]
Dict 4:
    Key1 = Value1
    Key2 = Array2 
                [Key3 = Value2]

    ]
```

I want to filter array based on key3 which is present in array as value of key2. 
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If your Key3 is a dictionary within Key2 and not an array, you could use:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Key2.Key3" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort, nil]];
```

Perhaps you can extract the Key3 value that you want to sort by and then use a dictionary that contains the sort key and the array of values.